# Creating a list of java strings in Unity C#

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface, facebook-share

I need to create a java list of java.lang.String in order to pass it to a method (for facebook sharing).

```
public E setPeopleIds(java.util.List<java.lang.String> peopleIds)
```

and this is how I call it

```
shareLinkContentBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setPeopleIds", ToJavaList(facebookID));
```

I can't figure out how to create a list of java strings from c# strings. This is what I've tried but I get a nre exception on the list.Call line

```
private AndroidJavaObject ToJavaList(string value)
    {
        AndroidJavaObject list = new AndroidJavaObject("java.util.List");
        list.Call("add", new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String", value));
        return list;
    }
```

Can't find any info as most of the topics are on xamarin or they are using arrays instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `java.util.List` is an interface and therefore cannot support methods like `add` by itself. You might have to use an implementation of a java list, like `java.util.ArrayList`

Another thing is that the latter function is creating a new list every time with only one element. I'm not sure if that's what you want.